# casperjs - How to skip part of code on die?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

How to skip part of a code on die? The script has to jump to the next label(for example, they all have name LABEL1)

```
   casper.start('http://google.com');
        casper.waitForSelector("input[name='q']",
            function success() {
              this.echo('Google.com page loaded');
            },
            function fail() {
                this.die('Google.com page WAS NOT loaded'); //meet die() function, 
                //need to jump on LABEL1 without stopping script
        });

    casper.then(function(){
      this.fillSelectors('body', {
        "input[name='q']":    'stackoverflow',
      }, true);
       this.echo('Filled form with search word - stackoverflow');
    });

    //here can be random number of casper steps
    casper.then(function() {
        this.captureSelector("search_results.png", "html");
    });
    //steps, steps
    casper.then(function() {
        this.echo("search_results.png");
    });

//LABEL1    

casper.thenOpen('http://wikipedia.org', function() {
    this.echo('HELLO'); 
 });

 casper.run();
```

I can't use suites for this purpose, because I have a custom casper module.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably try emitting a custom event which would execute your required step instead of calling a die(). http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#emitting-you-own-events